# Perl threads: How to make a producer?

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have a function that is very slow to run. I need input from that function in the main part of the program. So I would like to do something similar to the UNIX command `yes`, that produces as much input as is read, but only a little more than is needed. Unlike `yes` I do not want the values from STDIN but I want the values in a Perl queue.

In other words: This problem is not about selecting on file-handles, but on queues maintained by threads.

I imagine the meta code will look similar to this:

```
my $DataQueue = Thread::Queue->new();

my @producers;
my $no_of_threads = 10;
for (1..$no_of_threads) {
  push @producers, threads->create(\&producer);
}

for(<>) {
  # This should block until there is a value to dequeue
  # Maybe dequeue blocks by default - then this part is not a problem
  my $val = $DataQueue->dequeue();
  do_something($_,$val);
}
# We are done: The producers are no longer needed
kill @producers;

sub producer {
   while(1) {
      # How do I wait until the queue length is smaller than number of threads?
      wait_until(length of $DataQueue < $no_of_threads);
      $DataQueue->enqueue(compute_slow_value());
   }
}
```

But is there a more elegant way of doing this? I am especially unsure of how to do the `wait_until` part in an efficient way.

Comment: This feels an awful lot like an [`XY problem`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to 'top up' the queue? The whole point of a queue is it's a batch of work to be completed - you queue it up, and leave it to run. But you can always use `$DataQueue -> pending` to see how many items are in there.

Comment: The problem is that I want to prespawn processes. What will be passed around is handles for the processes. The spawning takes forever to warm up if done in the same thread. I am perfectly OK with not using a queue, which is why I ask if there is a more elegant way of doing it (e.g. without a queue).

Comment: Well, maybe it's just me, but I'm still not following what you're trying to do. There's no real reason you can't just start a thread to do your 'pre spawned' process, and just use a Semaphore or similar to indicate readiness. But really - a queue that's full of stuff, waiting for the 'spawn' to finish starting up, is ... just something that's waiting to go as soon as it's ready.

Comment: Ha: I can probably just use $DataQueue->limit = 2*$no_of_threads - assuming that this will block an enqueue() statement.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will probably work:

```
my $DataQueue = Thread::Queue->new();

my @producers;
my $no_of_threads = 10;
for (1..$no_of_threads) {
  push @producers, threads->create(\&producer);
}
$DataQueue->limit = 2 * $no_of_threads;

for(<>) {
  # This blocks until $DataQueue->pending > 0
  my $val = $DataQueue->dequeue();
  do_something($_,$val);
}
# We are done: The producers are no longer needed
kill @producers;

sub producer {
   while(1) {
      # enqueue will block until $DataQueue->pending < $DataQueue->limit
      $DataQueue->enqueue(compute_slow_value());
   }
}
```